# No delete button for a content reference

Tags: blocks, 8, nodes

I have a custom block type in Drupal 8 where I reference an unlimited amount of content nodes. Now that I want to delete a reference, there’s no delete button available or label that mentions any kind of operation at all.

[image: picture of content reference]

If you look at the "image reference field" there’s an operation to delete one image reference after another:

[image: picture of field reference]

Where can I find this delete option for content references? Simply leaving the field blank and pressing save will raise a validation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a value from your "Content Reference" field, simply leave the textfield of the desired row-to-delete blank (the multi-field widget for autocomplete fields doesn't have a delete button, it infers which rows should be maintained/deleted based on the presence of a value).

You've marked that field as required (notice the red asterisk at the top), so it must contain at least one value for the form to pass validation. If that's undesirable, just visit the manage fields page, edit the field, and remove the required constraint.